# Serilog setup for Asp.Net Core 2.0.1 not producing logs

Tags: c#, json, logging, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I am trying to set up Serilog as my logger in a multi project solution using Asp.Net Core 2.0.1, EF 2.0.1 and MVC 6.

I have set up Serilog, mostly following the guidelines from this blog post
[Set up Serilog post](https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2017/10/09/real-world-aspnet-core-logging-configuration/)

There is a problem with the json in that post, which I've corrected and is shown here

appsettings.json file

```
{
"ApplicationConfiguration": {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevelopmentConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestingConfigurationNetCoreTwo_Development;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"      
  },      
  "ApplicationInfo": {
    "VersionNumber": "1.0.0",
    "Author": "Jimbo",
    "ApplicationName": "CustomTemplate",
    "CreatedOn": "November 20, 2017"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Async",
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Seq"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "RollingFile",
              "Args": { "pathFormat": "Logs/log-{Date}.log" }
           }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId"],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "CustomTemplate" 
    }
  }
}
}
```

I have the logger configuration work in the Main method of Program.cs

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var currentEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"); 

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{currentEnv}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    //Configure logger
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        //do this for now
        //TODO:figure out how to add to Serilog config in appsettings.json
        .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
        .CreateLogger();

    Log.Information("Logger created");

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting web host");
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Web Host terminated unexpectedly");
        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
    //BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

And in my Startup method

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
```

I was assuming Serilog would create the Logs folder once I ran the application, but no Log folder or logs. I added a Logs folder to both the root of the solution, and the web app project and ran it again. No logs. The blog post author suggested looking in the machines root folder. I looked both in C and OneDrive main folders (Solution Files stored on OneDrive) but there were no logs there either.

I then noticed a stack trace warning

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
>     HResult=0x80070002
>     Message=The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Users\OneDrive\TestingConfigurationAspNetCore2\TestMvcApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\appsettings.json'.
>     Source=
>     StackTrace:
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()

I was getting this warning before, which is why I added the set bath path method in the configuration set up, because the application was failing at the code line

```
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
```

which was fairly obvious because in the bin folder the file isn't called appsettings.json, its called TestMvcApp.runtimeconfig.json.

Once I added .SetBasePath, the code ran through so I put a breakpoint after the configuration setup. The configuration object contains all the settings from my appsettings.json file, so why I am getting that stack trace error? I don't know but I'll bet a dollar it is why there are no logs (no log messages appear in the console either)

Any help on why the stack trace error or why there are no log messages being written to the log file or displayed on the console would be most appreciated.

Comment: This line `.WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")` indicates that you are not writing to a log file but to a logging server. Is that correct/your intention?

Comment: I added that after to see if i could write there when the rolling logs werent writing. they arent going there either

Comment: and unless I am wrong, Serilog should be writing to all the WriteTo's defined in the config

Comment: UseSerilog is missing in BuildHost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which was fairly obvious because in the bin folder the file isn't
>   called appsettings.json, its called TestMvcApp.runtimeconfig.json.

`TestMvcApp.runtimeconfig.json` is not your `appsettings.json`, it's a runtime configuration file as it's clear from the file name.

I bet that your `appsettings.json` is just not copied to the output directory during the build. To fix that select `appsettings.json` in Visual Studio Solution explorer, in context menu select properties and set 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy always' or 'Copy if newer':

Also your json configuration has several issues:

1. `Serilog` section should not be inside `ApplicationConfiguration` section. It should be on the same level, i.e top-level section.
2. You also has suspicious WriteTo section with one sink (`RollingFile`) inside another (`Async`). Check here [sample json configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile) for Serilog.
3. In order to use all those sinks (`Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile`, `Serilog.Sinks.Console`) you should install corresponding sink NuGets: [Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile/), [Serilog.Sinks.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Console/), etc.

Here is configuration file (with RollingFile sink only) that works fine for me:

```
{
    "ApplicationConfiguration": {
        "ConnectionStrings": {
            "DevelopmentConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestingConfigurationNetCoreTwo_Development;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
        },
        "ApplicationInfo": {
            "VersionNumber": "1.0.0",
            "Author": "Jimbo",
            "ApplicationName": "CustomTemplate",
            "CreatedOn": "November 20, 2017"
        }
    },
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [
            "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"
        ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "RollingFile",
                "Args": { "pathFormat": "c:\\log-{Date}.log" }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "CustomTemplate"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @CodeFuller...That cleared up removing the stack trace error and I removed the SetBasePath and it is running the application, and it is populating all the settings into configuration but still no log files ( I removed the WriteTo.Seq in the Logger configuration)

Comment: I added back the WriteTo.Seq and I am getting the logs in SEQ but still not in console or log files

Comment: @CodeFuller...Moving the Serilog section out of ApplicationConfiguration did the trick. All working now..TYVM...As a note, my Serilog section works fine. The WriteTo is telling the Async sink, to WriteTo the rolling file

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only logged some messages for my project. I'm not sure why. [Ondrej Balas's approach](https://ondrejbalas.com/using-serilog-with-asp-net-core-2-0/) worked better for me.

**Install** these Nuget packages:

- Serilog
- Serilog.AspNetCore
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration
- Serilog.Sinks.Console
- Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile

**Program.cs** needs `.UseSerilog()` added:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>

        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();
```

**Startup.cs** needs a couple of changes

one in the constructor:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();

        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

another in `Configure()`:

```
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    }
```

**appsettings.json** needs a Serilog config entry in **root**:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "System": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        { "Name": "Console" },
        {
            "Name": "RollingFile",
            "Args": {
                "pathFormat": "logs\\log-{Date}.log",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "My Application"
    }
}
```

Comment: ..."appsettings.json needs a Serilog config entry in root"...you would've figured that out if you read the last comment in the accepted answer